# Node JS Promise Location

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise

I am trying to multiple DB queries and a nested foreach function in Node but I am having trouble distinguishing where I should be putting the promise in my code. I am using Sequelize to manage the DB.

My code looks as follows:

```
client.findAll().then((result) => {
        result.forEach(item => {
            vehHistory.findAndCountAll({where:{
                dealerId:item.id,
                createdAt:{$gte:priorDate}
            }}).then((innerResult) => {
                clientArr.push({name: item.name, cars: innerResult.count, balance: innerResult.count*95, id: item.id});
            });
        });
    });
```

I am trying to build the promise so that I can get the value once  `clientArr` has been filled by the foreach loop and its nested DB call.

Would I place the promise around the `vehHistory.findAndCountAll` method then resolve it once the client array has been pushed or would I put the promise around the `clientArr.push` method?

Quite new to promises, coming from the C# world, this is all relatively new to me.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: forEach is simply the wrong tool for the job. It could be used to accomplish it, but a .map would give you an array that's ready to be used within a promise.all

Comment: @KevinB Thank you very much. I came right with the .map, appreciate the duplicate link as well, learnt something new tonight. Cheers!